# How to get image url in feedzilla

Tags: feed

I'm new to Feedzilla. (http://code.google.com/p/feedzilla-api/wiki/RestApi) I've been able to fetch news feed using their API for json, but I don't see anywhere in the docs where it mentions how to get images. Does anyone know how?  Thanks.

Comment: You can find the answer to your problem in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797727/grab-images-from-feedzilla/21223756#21223756