# Grab images from feedzilla

Tags: html, json, api, rss, feed

I am able to get the news data like post title and description but how do I get the news image by using the feedzilla API..

Nothing mentioned in the API documentation

http://w.feedzilla.com/api-overview

Answer (score 2):

When you get your list of articles (e.g. http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles.json) you can see that some of them have an attribute called 'enclosures' where feedzilla puts information about possible images of an article. As an example an article containing an image as JSON:

```
{"enclosures":[{"length":3489,"media_type":"image\/jpeg","uri":"http:\/\/news.com.au.feedsportal.com\/c\/34564\/f\/632403\/e\/1\/s\/36174fe5\/l\/0Lresources30Bnews0N0Bau0Cimages0C20A140C0A10C190C122680A50C4485310Erosetta0Bjpg\/448531-rosetta.jpg"}],"publish_date":"Sun, 19 Jan 2014 14:00:00 +0100","source":"Cnet","source_url":"http:\/\/feeds.feedburner.com\/newscomauworldnewsndm","summary":"ONE of the most ambitious missions in the history of space goes into high-risk\u000amode today when a comet-chasing probe wakes up.\u000a\u000a\u000a\u000a\u000a\u000a\u000a\u000a\u000a","title":"Comet-chasing probe to wake up (Cnet)","url":"http:\/\/news.feedzilla.com\/en_us\/stories\/top-news\/353840990?client_source=api&format=json"}
```

Note that this attribute is optional.